Has EF Core introduced a change in behavior that allows direct entity projection in LINQ queries?
I'm working with EF Core 8 and the MySql provider (Pomelo) in my .NET project. I'm encountering a curious situation where the following code snippet runs without needing Dtos and doesn't produce the error "The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"
What changed in EF Core, or is there something wrong with my code? I remember you needed to use Dtos for this situation or else it will throw an error. Any insights would be appreciated!
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

var list = DbContext.Products
    .Select(x => new Product()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Name = x.Name,
        Qty = x.Qty,
    }).ToList();

I'm using the following EF Core package references:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.2" />


EF Core just not introduced EF6's strange limitation.

runs without needing Dtos what does this mean? This code always worked. When did it not work, and what were the exact circumstances - actual entity code, provider and version numbers ?

It was an unintended (and unusual) limitation in Entity Framework 6.
In EF Core, this limitation has been removed, allowing you to project to a model class without encountering translation errors.

I don't remember ever seeing this error, so the "change" may be going all the way back to EF Core 1

@PanagiotisKanavos. SO is full with such answers for EF6

And even back then I don't remember ever getting this error. Either I want to load the entire object so I used Product or I wanted only a few properties so I used anonymous types or a DTO, so I don't have to deal with a minefield of NULLs.

I think the actual problem or something similar to it has been discussed in here for EF Core: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31315

@Joseph, it is different case. They discussed about detecting which properties can be translatable after custom projection. Don't find analogues, it was synthetic limitation.

That has always worked, and it's identical to just running
var list = DbContext.Products.ToList();

So explain to me when does this error usually occurs.

Perhaps when the constructed entity is referenced by other query logic?

It worked in EF-core, not EF6 and earlier. Also, there's very important difference with DbContext.Products.ToList(): the new entities aren't tracked.
